# Submitting Code Snippets via a Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Looking for some help on submitting a form that contains PHP code. Basically I have a textarea  that I want people to be able to submit code and this then will be emailed to me and formatted way. The code submitted might look like this:

```
<?php print "Testing"; ?>
```

I am submitting the form via Ajax, which I have got all working. However my problem is when I try to send code from the textarea the field is blank in the email I receive.

I have tried escaping the field with Ajax before sending but then the email then contains a lot of escaped characters.

Basically how do I get the code to send correctly and look the same as that has been typed in the field?

---

I have tried to get this to work by unescaping the characters. I am actually use a .NET system. Is there a specific command t do this?

My Code behind looks like this:

```
   [RestExtensionMethod()]
    public static string CreateSnippet(int processid)
    {

        //here we find form values posted to the current page
        HttpRequest post = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string email = post["email"];
        string comment = post["comment"];
        string name = post["name"];
        string website = post["website"];

        var mailcontent = new StringBuilder();
        mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Name", name);
        mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Email", email);
        mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Website", website);
        mailcontent.AppendFormat(EmailLineFormat, "Message", comment);

        // Send the email
        library.SendMail("email@email.co.uk", "email@email.co.uk", "Contact Form Enquiry", mailcontent.ToString(), true);

        //if nothing gets created, we return zero
        return "success";

    }
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
// submit
        $contactUsForm.submit(function() {

            $loader.show();

                            var url = "/base/Form4Umbraco/url.aspx";

                            var name = jQuery("#tbName").val();
                            var email = jQuery("#tbEmail").val();
                            var website = jQuery("#tbWebsite").val();
                            var comment = jQuery("#tbEnquiry").val();

                            jQuery.post(url, { name: name, email: email, website: website, comment: comment },
                               $contactUsSuccess.fadeIn()
                            );

            return false;
        });
```

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated.
Robert

Comment: Could you please post the jQuery code which calls the AJAX, and also the PHP which is sending the email.

Comment: I have added the .net code and the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Before your Ajax Request escape the PHP-Code and as It seems that you are getting simple Text-Email then before sending e-mail from your PHP-Script unescape your code passed from the textarea

Comment: Ah ok so I need to unescape the code again before actually sending the code. I will give it a shot.